# apollo / graphql to query for a list of ids

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I want to query for a specific list of items so that

```
query queryItemsById ($ids: Array<ID!>) {
   foundNodes {
     id
     name
   }
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with a custom resolver on the graphql side?

Or will I have to make list.length number of queries for each foundNode?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely doable in GraphQL.

If you're using `graphql-js`:

```
new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
      queryItemsById: {
        type: new GraphQLList(ItemType),
        resolve: (_, { ids }) => Item.findAll(ids)
      }
    }
  })
})
```